# How to trim dictionary for both empty and null values

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

How to remove dictionary for empty or null value
From API response data some times it get values or empty "" or null.

```
    struct StudentField {

        var studentID: String?
        var studentName: String?
        var subjectName: String?
        init(_ json: JSON) {
            studentID = json["student_id"].stringValue
            studentName = json["name_id"].stringValue
            subjectName = json["subject_Name"].stringValue

          let studentDict =   [
            "Id": studentID,
            "name": studentName,
            "subject": subjectName
           ]

            let cleanDictionary = studentDict.reduce(into: [String: Any]()) { $0[$1.key] = $1.value }

         var dict = [String:Any]()
            for element in cleanDictionary {
                print(element)
}
```

How to Trip dictionary for Empty "" null value ?

```
input ["student_id": "" "name_id": "", "subject_Name" : "Maths"]
OutPut ["subject_Name" : "Maths"]
```

Comment: Make yourself a favor and drop SwiftyJSON. You should start using Codable protocol. BTW if you post your JSON String would be much easier to help you. `print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) ?? "nil")`

Comment: Btw If you don't want empty strings you should use `string` instead of `stringValue` which would return `nil`

Answer (score 1):

You can filter dictionary by using `filter` method:

```
var model2 = ["student_id": "" ,"name_id": "", "subject_Name" : "Maths"]
var filteredEmpty = model2.filter( { !$0.value.isEmpty })
print(filteredEmpty)
```

Output is :

```
["subject_Name": "Maths"]
```

Or you can use `compactMapValues` like :

```
model2 = model2.compactMapValues { val -> String? in
if val != "" {
    return val
}
return nil
}
print(model2)
```

Output is :

```
["subject_Name": "Maths"]
```